# How to make custom select dropdown in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a custom select dropdown using hooks, I tried it but could not be done. onClick on dropdown-item this item text should be print in  tag, plz help me in this.

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";


function App() {
  return(
  
    <>
    <div className="dropdown">
  <button className="btn btn-secondary" type="button" >
    Selected dropdown text should be here
  </button>
  <ul className="dropdown-menu" >
    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Tesla</a></li>
    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Volvo</a></li>
    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Mercedes</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    
    </>
  )
  
}

export default App;
```

```css
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suggest having an "isOpen" state, which you use as a condition to display the <ul>. There are plenty youtube tutorials that show how to build something like this.

Comment: Yes, I have done that hide show, but I want to get the value onClick.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";


function App() {

  const [dropdown, setdropdown] = useState(0);
  const dropdownList = ["Tesla", "Volvo", "Mercedes"];

  const dropdownListClick = index => {
    setdropdown(index);
  };
  
  return(
  
    <>
   <div className="dropdown">
          <button
            className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            {dropdownList[dropdown]}
          </button>
          <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            {dropdownList.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <a
                    className="dropdown-item"
                    href="#"
                    onClick={() => dropdownListClick(index)}
                    key={index}
                  >
                    {value}
                  </a>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
    
    </>
  )
  
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Here, i have done this**

Answer (score 0):

**Write your css code as you want**

Here is the jsx I wrote to make a custom Select

```js
const App = () => {
  const menuItems = ["Bengali", "Hindi", "Arabic", "English", "Spanish"];
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("Menu");

  const handleOptionClick = (option) => {
    setSelectedOption(option);
  };
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <button className="transparent__btn" type="button">
        {" "}
        {selectedOption}
        <ul className="dropdown__item">
          {menuItems.map((menuItem) => (
            <li key={menuItem}>
              <a
                className="dropdown-item"
                href="#"
                onClick={() => handleOptionClick(menuItem)}
              >
                {menuItem}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```